# $P+cQ$ is invertible for a finite number

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Since $C$ is a field and $P,Q \in M_n(C)$ are invertible, can any body show me that $P+cQ$ is invertible for all but a finite number $c \in C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: The map $c \mapsto \det(P + cQ)$ is a polynomial. How many zeros can a non-zero (why is this non-zero?) have?

Comment: did you mean that about zero polynomial? so that will affect to invertible?

Answer (score 2):

$\det(P+cQ)=\det(PQ^{-1}+cI).\det(Q)=0$

as $\det(Q) \neq 0$ so $\det(PQ^{-1}+cI)=0$ (which holds for finite number of $c$)

hence the result.